# Nested Meteor (Blaze) templates controlled by parent

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm trying to avoid repetitive template code for forms that are essential the same when creating or editing new items.

For example, something like this:

```
<template name="createOrEdit">

   <form role="form">

      <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title"/ value="{{title}}">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

   </form>

</template>

<template name="create">   
  {{> createOrEdit}}
</template>

<template name="edit">   
  {{> createOrEdit}}
</template>
```

Then, I could created separate template handlers:

```
Template.create.events(...
Template.edit.events(...
```

However, those parent template wrappers won't get the events for the main child template.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those parent templates can get the events from child template. Use it like this:

```
Template.create.events({
  'click .btn':function(){

  }
})

Template.edit.events({
  'click .btn':function(){

  }
})
```

In `Template.createOrEdit.events` object you keep events used by both templates and in `Template.edit.events` and `Template.create.events` specific code for each.

[see proof](http://meteorpad.com/pad/scZRZ8rZkN6vsPcTC) and 
[source code](https://github.com/parhelium/laboratory/tree/master/meteor/reusable-forms)

This approach is really nice as you can customize form by passing some variables:

```
{{# create btnText="create" }}{{/create}}
{{# edit btnText="update" }}{{/edit}}
```

And in `createOrEdit` template you can use variable `btnText` to change button's label.